# Getting Error message as NULL while invoking a service in one spring boot application from another spring boot application using RestTemplate

Tags: spring, http, spring-boot, resttemplate

AM trying to invoke a spring boot microservice from another application.

Here is my Server code, if any exception occurs

```
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)
                .body(new com.test.models.ResponseEntity("Tenant details 
         not found"));
```

Here is my client code,

```
ResponseEntity<Object> uploadResponse = 
          restTemplate.exchange("http://TESTAPPLICATION/v1/object",
          HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, Object.class);
```

Am getting a response as

```
  Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 403 null
```

If I hit my endpoint from PostMan, am getting proper response message.

But from my client-side application am getting response message as null. Please let me know what is going wrong.

UPDATE:

Screenshot.
  Client Responds with INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR. But from my server iam responding 403. 
[image]

Comment: are you providing any authentication for your service, because 403 means permission denied

Comment: please share screen shot of postman response with headers and body sections

Comment: Ravat, I am checking if a user exists in db, else am responding with 403,                                                                                               
 return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)
                .body(new com.test.models.ResponseEntity("Tenant details 
         not found")); in my server with the error message. Issue is am not getting the error message in my client application, which invokes using restTemplate